# fetching row data php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search engine and im trying to open every result in a new window and am not sure what would be the best way to do it. on my search result page "search.php" I am using

```
$go = "go.php?url=";
print "<a href='".$go."".($row['id'])."' title='".($row['title'])."' rel='nofollow' target='_blank'>".html_entity_decode($row['title'])."</a>";
```

which would take you to a page like http://website.com/go.php?url=37290

37290 would be the row id and now I have to query it so I can get all the rest of the info and I am having trouble. I know this is really easy but any help would be much appreciated.

on go.php I am using this right now just to show that im grabbing the id from url=37290

```
<?php print $_GET['url']?>
```

which obviously prints out 37290 but now I need to query that id in the db and fetch the extra db info.

I need to fetch link_id, title, and url

What would be a good way to do this? 
Thanks.

EDIT:
i would need a query like

select link_id, title, url from search1_links

I hope that shows my db structure better. The db is name is data1

I assuming I need something like

```
if ($_GET['url']){
```

sql query stuff here.
}

EDIT:

My main problem is I cannot figure out how to make a query with $_GET['url']
url is the id
I can do the sql I just need to know how to make a query with the id $_GET['url'] gives me.

Comment: Please share your db structure so we know what "link_id", "title" etc means.

Comment: Is link_id the same than the id which is in the url ?

Comment: yes, all the info i seek is in the same row. sory readi ti wrong, but yes link_id is what is in the url.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with, the sql statement?

Comment: yes the sql statement is what i am having trouble with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I would do something like:

```
$id = isset($_GET['url']) ? ((int) $_GET['url']) : NULL;
if (!empty($id))
{
  $sql = "SELECT title FROM some_table WHERE link_id = $id";
  // etc.
}
else
{
  // some error message and exit
}
```

Although I really would use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), but that´s another story.

Answer (score 0):

```
//use correct db server/user/password
mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$result = mysql_query(<<<SQL
   SELECT link_id, title FROM db1.t1 WHERE id = '$id'
SQL
);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "$row[link_id] $row[title]";
```

Comment: What an odd way to create a query

Comment: You're going to have to be waaay more specific.